# CSSグリッドで画像の位置を指定しても、指定した位置に画像がフィットしません。

Tags: css, html5

**現象**
CSSグリッドで画像(`image_0.svg`)の位置を指定しても、指定した位置に画像がフィットしません。

**期待値**
画像が`grid-column: 3 / -3;` `grid-row: facebook-logo;`で指定した位置にフィットさせたい。

**再現手順**
下記のコードを実行する。ちなみに、Facebookのモバイルでのログインページを模写コーディングしています。

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Facebook-copy</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <i class="fas fa-mobile-alt"></i>
        <div class="header-text">
            <p>iPhone用Facebookで高速ブラウジング</p>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="main">

        <img class="facebook-logo-image" src="./image_0.svg" alt="facebookのロゴ">

        <div class="login-form">
            <form action="#">
                <input type="email" name="mail">
                <input type="password" name="pw">
                <input type="submit" value="ログイン">
                <p>または</p>
                <a href="#">パスワードを忘れた場合</a>
                <hr>
                <button>新しいアカウントを作成</button>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="under-login-form-text">
            <p>有名人、バンド、ビジネスのために<a href="#">Facebookページを作成</a></p>
        </div>

    </div>

    <footer>

        <div class="language">
            <p>日本語</p>
            <a href="#">English (US)</a>
            <a href="#">Português (Brasil) </a>
            <a href="#">中文(简体) </a>
            <a href="#">Español</a>
            <a href="#">Français (France) </a>
            <a href="#">Deutsch</a>
            <button>＋</button>
        </div>

        <div class="footer-menu">
            <a href="#">Facebookについて</a>
            <p>・</p>
            <a href="#">ヘルプ</a>
            <p>・</p>
            <a href="#">その他</a>
        </div>

        <div class="copy-right">
            <small>Facebook Inc.</small>
        </div>

    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

stylesheet.css

```
@charset "UTF-8";

/* 基本設定 */

* {
    margin: 0;
}

/* ページ全体の設定 */
body {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 15px 52px 1fr 52px 15px;
    grid-template-rows: 
            [head] 45px
            [facebook-logo] 40px
            [login-form] 175px
            [or] 15px
            [create-new-account] 51px
            [forget-password] 27px
            [blank-middle] 35px
            [language] 85px
            [footer-menu] 11px
            [copy-right] 15px
            [blank-footer] 7px;
}

/* ヘッダー */
header {
    grid-column: 2 / -2;
    grid-row: head;
}

/* facebookロゴ */
.facebook-logo-img {
    grid-column: 3 / -3;
    grid-row: facebook-logo;
    width: 112px;
    height: 39.42px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

皆さまご回答宜しくお願い致します。

**追記**
`grid-template-rows`プロパティで指定している名前付き行のいくつかがどうしてCSSに存在しないのかと言いますと、まだ作成途中でCSSを記述している途中だからです。

Answer (score 1):

`stylesheet.css`の`.facebook-logo-img`を`.facebook-logo-image`に変更して、class名が`facebook-logo-image`のimgタグをグリッドアイテムにしたら、想定したグリッドコンテナに画像がフィットしました。

参考リンク
[CSS Gridの実装で必要な基礎知識、主要なプロパティと用語をくわしく解説](https://coliss.com/articles/build-websites/operation/css/css-grid-layout-terminology.html)

**追記**

下記はソースコード
`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Facebook-copy</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <i class="fas fa-mobile-alt"></i>
        <div class="header-text">
            <p>iPhone用Facebookで高速ブラウジング</p>
        </div>
    </header>
    <img class="facebook-logo-image" src="./image_0.svg" alt="facebookのロゴ">
</body>
</html>
```

`stylesheet.css`

```
@charset "UTF-8";

/* 基本設定 */

* {
    margin: 0;
}

/* ページ全体の設定 */
body {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 15px 52px 1fr 52px 15px;
    grid-template-rows: 
            [head] 45px
            [facebook-logo] 40px

/* ヘッダー */
header {
    grid-column: 2 / -2;
    grid-row: head;
}

/* facebookロゴ */
.facebook-logo-image {
    grid-column: 3 / -3;
    grid-row: facebook-logo;
    width: 112px;
    height: 39.42px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```